# jQuery: Binding all Events from one Control to another

Tags: jquery, events, inheritance, controls, bind

this might be a simple questions but I can't get my head around it.

I have 2 jQuery UI Slider Controls.
One is generated as part of the Plugin I am using but since it is positioned at a totally wrong place in the layout and the Plugin references it through the use of parent() etc I have simply set it to be hidden.

Now there is the second slider control which I have created and which is supposed to have the exact same functionality as the autogenerated control that I have hidden.

How can I tell the second control that it is supposed to behave just as the first control?

so to say:

`#control_1 = hidden / has all the needed functionality but is positioned wrong in the layout`

```
#control_2 = needs to inherit all events from #control_1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the original control:

```
var newControl = $("#control_1").clone(true, true);
```

You could then append it to the DOM in the required place. The `true` arguments are needed to also clone any event handlers bound to the element, as they are ignored by default.

Comment: That worked as far as copying the events et al. But when I try to move the handler in the copied control the handler is not actually moving.

I've actually settled with creating my own code for the needed functionality.

Thanks anyway. I'll award you the answer for leading me in the right direction :)